# Need equivalent C# code for a Eval Data Binding operation that usually occurs in ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

The first excerpt of code is from an ASPX page:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" Width="60%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"  HeaderStyle-Width="60%" ID="commentRadGrid" AllowFilteringByColumn="False" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AllowPaging="true"  OnNeedDataSource="someRadGrid"    PageSize="100" Skin="Default" AllowSorting="true" AutoPostBack="true" ShowStatusBar="true" AllowCustomPaging="True"
    GridLines="none" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" >
        <MasterTableView Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="False" GridLines="none">
            <ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="60%"/>
            <Columns>

blah blah blah
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn Visible="false" AllowFiltering="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="invisibleSectionResourceDatabaseIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SectionBasedResourceDatabaseIDAsString")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
blah blah blah
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

I'm trying to create the Label at Runtime, and also configure properties of the Label at Runtime:

```
            invisibleSectionResourceDatabaseIDLabel = new Label();
            invisibleSectionResourceDatabaseIDLabel.ID = colname;
            invisibleSectionResourceDatabaseIDLabel.Text =
```

I don't know how to set the invisibleSectionResourceDatabaseIDLabel.Text value to an equivalent C# code to the <%# Eval("SectionBasedResourceDatabaseIDAsString")%> expression in C# at Runtime.

Please help me set the invisibleSectionResourceDatabaseIDLabel.Text value at runtime

Answer (score 1):

```
invisibleSectionResourceDatabaseIDLabel.Text = DataBinder.Eval(yourBindingObject, "SectionBasedResourceDatabaseIDAsString).ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry for sounding so naive.  What do you mean by the "yourBindingObject" ?  Is "yourBindingObject" the DataTable that contains the data?  Or is it the ASP Label that I am programmatically creating and configuring?

Comment: yourBindingObject is the object, for which you want to get SectionBasedResourceDatabaseIDAsString value. It may be DataRow (not DataTable) or some other object. What concrete value you want to assign to your label text? And where in runtime this value is stored?